# Will multiple columns concatenate in the same order if using STUFF and For Xml Path

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb107/3 for an example schema and query I want to run.
I want to use the STUFF and FOR XML PATH('') solution to concatenate columns having grouped by another column.

If I use this method to concatenate multiple columnns into a csv list, am I guaranteed that the order will be the same in each concatenated string? So if the table was:

```
ID  Col1 Col2 Col3
1   1    1    1   
1   2    2    2
1   3    3    3
2   4    4    4
2   5    5    5
2   5    5    5
```

Am I certain that if Col1 is concatenated such that the result is:

```
ID Col1Concatenated
1  1,2,3
2  4,5,6
```

That Col2Concatenated will also be in the same order ("1,2,3", "4,5,6") as opposed to ("2,3,1", "5,6,4") for example?

This solution will only work for me if the index of each row's value is the same in each of the concatenated values. i.e. first row is first in each csv list, second row is second in each csv list etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `ORDER BY` clause in the query within your `STUFF` function

Comment: Thank you. I assumed ORDER BY wouldn't be allowed and didn't even try it.

Comment: Be careful that you add it in the right place.  Put it right above the "FOR XML PATH" statement.  Just yesterday, I put it in a subquery.  The ORDER BY was accepted, but a no-op.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's where I'd put it alright, seemed to make the most sense to put it there. The fact that the results looked correct without the ORDER BY it's hard to tell if it made a difference